# unable to retrieve environment variable from array values in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a case where I need to fetch the environment variable and pass it to a function in bash script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

algorithm_settings=(env1 env2 env3 env4)

cnt=${#algorithm_settings[@]}
for ((i=0;i<cnt;i++)); do
   printf '%s\n' "${algorithm_settings[i]}"
done
```

This prints:

```
env1
env2
env3
env4
```

I have set the value of env1 as `export env1=1.0.1`

I get the value of `env1` by using the command `printenv env1`

How do I store this value(1.0.1) in a variable?

Comment: `variable="${!algorithm_settings[0]}"`?

Comment: I suggest: `algorithm_settings=("$env1" "$env2" "$env3" "$env4")`

Comment: @Cyrus `algorithm_settings` array is used in multiple places in my case. I am using it as key : value pair where key corresponds to name of environment variable and value with value stored in that environment variable.